# Trouble on responding to a HTTP Request when counting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, http, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to implement an API. I would like to solve some strange problems that I have on returning data after a web client HTTP GET Request. In few words, problems are in the response body returned values for which I get "too much" `""` (see the examples belowe) and, sometime, in returning JSON data.

On the web service side in my *Rack middleware* I have:

```
class Testing
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    accounts = Account.find([1,2,3])

    resp_test = accounts.count
    [200, {}, resp_test] # No [200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, resp_test]
  end
end
```

On the client side if I see the response I have

```
# debug response.body 
---
```

In this case the problem is the `accounts.count` that returns a value of `""` in the response body. It is possible that `accounts.count` doesn't do what it should do.

I also encountered some problems when I didn't return JSON data. For example, debugging variables on the client side, sometime I got a body response value of `""` if I didn't return JSON DATA like this:

```
# On the service side in the Rack middleware file
[200, {}, resp_test] # No[200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, resp_test.to_json]
```

The response are:

```
# Case don't returning JSON data
# debug response.body 
---

# Case returning JSON data
# debug response.body 
--- test_value
```

**What is the problem? If it is `accounts.count` or `Account.find([1,2,3])`, how can I make that to work in order to return correct value?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your middleware should be after `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement` when calling `rake middleware`

second try to return `resp_test.to_s`